# How to apply a point cut on constructor that has around advice?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Hello everyone i am new to aspectj. In my program i need to apply apply a pointcut on cunstructor invocation i.e. `new Myclass();` .

I have a point cut like:

```
package pak;
//import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.*;

public aspect HookYepmeAspect {


    pointcut constructorPkt(int paramInt, String paramString1):
        call(public  MyClass.new(int , String ))  && args( paramInt,  paramString1);

    void around(int paramInt, String paramString1):constructorPkt(paramInt,  paramString1) && within(com.yepme.*)
    {
        proceed(paramInt,  paramString1);
    }
}
```

but it gives me worning that :

```
applying to join point that doesn't return void: constructor-call(void com.yepme.Contact.<init>(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) HookYepmeAspect.aj  /TmpHookAspectProject/src/pak   line 63 Java Problem
```

i also tried `int` as a return type of advice.So please can anyone tell me what i am making mistake. what should i do in this case .

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you are intercepting a function that doesn't return void.

Around advice should not return void, but capture the output from the call and return that.

```
public Object around(int paramInt, String paramString1):constructorPkt(paramInt,  paramString1) && within(com.yepme.*)
    {
        return proceed(paramInt,  paramString1);
    }
```

Use Object so that it will work for all the object types that the matching adviced functions(constructors) might return.